# ubuntu server to support unlimited or 100+ telnet users

Tags: apt

I am new to ubuntu.

I have installed ubuntu server 12.10 and I want it to support unlimited or 100+ telnet instances or sessions. How shall I go about it.

Regards

Rohan

Answer (score 1):

> Installation

You start by setting up a telnet server. This can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd telnetd
```

Information about these package can be found here: [xinetd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/xinetd) [telnetd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/telnetd)

> Configuration

In `/etc/inetd.conf` there are configuration options (listed this one because it also has the option to set the amount of connections/users):

```
# Simple configuration file for xinetd
#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/
defaults
{
# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info
instances = 60
log_type = SYSLOG authpriv
log_on_success = HOST PID
log_on_failure = HOST
cps = 25 30
}
```

- `instances` is the number of connections and `unlimited` can be used instead of a number.
- There is also `/etc/services` where you can change the port number where telnet should listen too.
- And there is `/etc/xinetd.d/telnet` where you can set up IP ranges that are allowed (`only_from =`) or disallowed (`no_access =`) access and also access time (`access_times =`).

> (Re-)starting telnet service

To apply changes you then need to restart services with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

> -- **Warning** --
>
> Telnet is fast but also insecure. It sends all your text, including your password, in plain text that can be read by anyone with the right tools. SSH, on the other hand, encrypts all your communication and so is more resource-intensive but secure even a government security agency sniffing your packets for some reason would still have a hard time cracking the encryption. If you are looking for SSH server configuration in Ubuntu [check here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/securely-administer-your-ubuntu-server-remotely.html).